# Uploadify - Rename File

Tags: php, javascript, uploadify

I'm using uploadify, but I'm not too sure how to edit the php to rename the uploaded files.

Basically, a user can upload upto 4 files and they should be named something like 1-img-1, 1-img-2, 1-img-3, 1-img-4 - the first number being a user id (which can be accessed via the POST).

Here's the uploadify php script:

```
<?php
/*
UploadiFive
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
*/

// Set the uplaod directory
$uploadDir = '/img/listing_images/';

// Set the allowed file extensions
$fileTypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'); // Allowed file extensions

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) { $i++;
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $uploadDir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $uploadDir;
    $targetFile = $uploadDir . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the filetype
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    if (in_array(strtolower($fileParts['extension']), $fileTypes)) {
    // Save the file
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
    echo 1;

} else {

    // The file type wasn't allowed
    echo 'Invalid file type.';

}
}
?>
```

Just wondering if someone could help to show me how I would rename the uploaded files?

Comment: your script is going to allow for a total compromise of your server, especially if `$uploadDir` is within your document root. Your "security" is anything but. filtering by user-supplied filename is **NOT** enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate a unique key and safe the file with that name, untested example:

```
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$unique_hash = hash_hmac("md5", file_get_contents($_FILES['Filedata']['name']), SALT);
$targetFile = $uploadDir . $unique_hash . $fileParts['extension'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the $targetFile variable value and move the declaration & assignment of $fileParts like this:

```
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$targetFile = $uploadDir . '1-img-' . $i . $fileParts['extension'];
```

Comment: That's awesome. It's renaming the files, though it seems to be stopping after the first image upload?

Comment: Hmm. I'm guessing each file is POSTed in a separate request so the file names are all being set to the same value ($i is always 1). Each file would then overwrite the previous and it would look like only a single file is uploaded. The client would need to send a counter and then the code might look like `$counter = $_FILES['Filedata']['counter']; $targetFile = $uploadDir . '1-img-' . $counter . $fileParts['extension'];`

Comment: Marc B makes a good point, but security is a separate topic. http://bit.ly/SeHa6Z has some must-haves for securing your uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the original uploadify.php

```
<?php
/*
Uploadify
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
Released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php> 
*/

// Define a destination
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
}
?>
```

I just do it like this.

```
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' .rand_string(20).'.'.$fileParts['extension'];
```

Where rand_string() is a function that generates random stings.

This one generates different names (random) each time you upload a file. Hope this helps!